# Qztray HTML file printing issue, html print left side of the page

Tags: javascript, java, printing, qz-tray

I am trying to print the HTML file using QZtray 2.0. File is printing on the left side of the page. I have set the height and width too, but same issue.

```
function printHTML() 
{
    var printData = [
    {
         type: 'html',
         format: 'file',
         data: test.html
    }];
    return qz.print(config, printData);
}
```

I have set the options,

```
`colorType: 'Color',
copies: 1,
density: 600,
duplex: '',
interpolation: '',
jobName: null,
legacy: '',
margins: 0,
orientation: 'Portrait',
paperThickness: '',
printerTray: '',
rasterize: true,
rotation: 0,
scaleContent: true,
size: null,
units: 'in'`
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue, by installing the beta version of qztraty 2.1, set the proper width and checked the printed document which looks proper.